# JSON to JSON Mapper

Tags: json, etl, esb

We need a JSON mapper from Type-A to Type-B ( i.e. JSON to JSON string). I'm aware of ESB tools which has mapping for XML to XML like IBM ESB.

So do we have any open source tool or paid application

1. Which has an editor to do mapping of JSON to other JSON , with capability to do some basic operations like formatting, etc
2. Can this transformation be exposed as REST service
3. If needed be, extract this transformation logic as JAR file and other team can use it

Thanks.

Comment: Right now, I think you are out of luck. (But check back next week - someone should be working on a tool like this by then.) In the meantime, the only method I can think of that may be capable of what you need is a JSON --> AObject --> BObject --> JSON transform, where one object is mapped onto another before being converted back to that object's JSON representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manjesh,

I have good news for you.  There is indeed an open source program that will accomplish this for you.  Talend Open Studio (TOS) ESB (not to be confused with their TOS for Data Integration).  Any ESB tool should do this quite easily.  See below:

Image 1 shows in SoapUI where I am calling a REST service, passing the JSON  prefix: team1,  team: Giants is sent in.  I return:  Prefix: Cowboys are better than, Team: Giants.  I could have done other manipulations (including changing the json structure) but put together a simple example.

[image]

The next image shows the Talend REST service implementation within Talend:

[image]

finally, I show the internals of the component (tXMLMap_2) where I manipulate the json data.

[image]